# I am unable to get my code to count and reset to zero

Tags: python, regex

I am having an issue with creating code that will count when a pattern is not matched and reset back to 0 once that pattern has a match using regular expression. I will list a an example of the file and try to attempt to demonstrate what I am looking to do. No matter how many matches are in the file I receive a -1. I am also not sure how the numbers should be formatted in the text file.

regEx56 "locates all numbers that have 56 in it regardless of location) 256 526 065.
regEx57 "The same as 56 but uses 57 instead"

```
p3text file.      python count:    56     57
107                                 -1     -1
328                                  -2     -2
156                                   0     -3
725                                   -1     0
```

Here is my code:

```
import re

my_p3text = open("p3text.txt", "r")
p3data = my_p3text.read()


regEx56 = str(re.findall(r'\b[0-4]*(?:5[0-4]?6|6[0-4]?5)[0-4]*\b',p3data))
regEx57 =str(r'\b[0-4]*(?:5[0-4]?7|7[0-4]?5)[0-4]*\b',p3data)



for line in my_p3text:
    match=regEx56.search(line)
    count = 0
    print (match)


else:
    count = -1
print (count)
```

Comment: What exactly is the pattern. Could you give an example please?

Comment: so the list of numbers are: 107 328 156 725. I want to track numbers with 56 and 75 the regular expressions catch them. but the count is not working. r'\b[0-4]*(?:5[0-4]?6|6[0-4]?5)[0-4]*\b' = any combination of 56 in a 3 digit number and '\b[0-4]*(?:5[0-4]?7|7[0-4]?5)[0-4]*\b' does the same for 57

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:

```
for line in my_p3text:
    match=regEx56.search(line)
    count = 0
    print (match)


else:
    count = -1
```

means that when there are no more lines, it will print -1, which is always. Put an if-else statement inside the for loop.

Also, right now your numbers can only start with 0-4, 5, 6 or 7; with a possible 0-4 between 6-7 and 5 (and vice versa). It also ends in a similar fashion to the way it starts.

If this is what you want, then it's fine, otherwise try...

```
(\d*((5\d*?[67])|([67]\d*?5))\d*)
```